# In "much to Anthony’s and everyone else’s" - Do I need an apostrophe right after Anthony?

Tags: punctuation, possessives

> . . . much to **Anthony**’s and everyone else’s amusement

Do I need an apostrophe right after Anthony here?

Comment: Yes, since the "amusement" belongs to Anthony and everyone else.

Comment: @Peter what about the *compound possession*?

Comment: @user178049 It would depend if you think "Anthony" and "everyone else" possess the same sense of "amusement", I would think not since "everyone else" is a fairly broad category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need the apostrophe after *Anthony* since the amusement would normally be seen as shared by him and everyone else.

Presumeably, Anthony and the others are reacting to the same event with the same thing: amusement.

One might argue that Anthony's amusement may differ from that experienced by everyone else, or it's conceivable that context may establish such a situation, but a plain reading of the text would suggest that the amusement is shared.

If individuation was intended, it would probably be styled to show that explicitly, eg *Anthony's amusement was quite different from everyone else's.*

http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/apostrophe.html#possessives